# How to upgrade git based recipe using devtool krogoth in yocto

Tags: git, embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I am using `krogoth` branch for yocto development.

Initially I created a workspace and created my own recipes for some open-source python repositories and they are working well on the board. Hence, I shifted them to my own meta layer.

I adapted the codes for the repositories and now each of them is about 2 commits ahead.

In `krogoth` in know that one can do the following:

```
devtool upgrade recipe_name --srcrev <commit_hash>
```

I executed the same for one of my recipes and stumbled upon the error:

```
Error: `/home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/workspace/recipes/gpsinflux/gpsinflux_git.bb` and `/home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/workspace/recipes/gpsinflux/gpsinflux_git.bb` are the same file
```

it states the the `gpsinflux_git.bb` is the same. It should be because I have made the recipes like standard Python recipes in Poky:

- `recipe.inc`
- `recipe_git.bb`

within every `.bb` file the following line is included:

```
inherit setuptools3 pypi

include recipe.inc
```

And `recipe.inc` example as follows:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=25498e25581c2413266e28dd693d4725"

HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/iotfablab/gpsinflux"
SUMMARY = "Extract GPS values and store into InfluxDB"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/iotfablab/gpsinflux.git;protocol=http"

# Modify these as desired
#PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "7a89e1a0bf489cc449acfaa2c9be72ec1fda4ea1"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"


RDEPENDS_${PN} += "influxdb-python pynmea2 ${PYTHON_PN}-pyserial"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "${PYTHON_PN}-argparse ${PYTHON_PN}-core ${PYTHON_PN}-json ${PYTHON_PN}-lang ${PYTHON_PN}-logging"
```

I can of course directly change the `SRCREV` directly in the recipe to the latest hash but wanted to use `devtool` to have a consistent workflow in Yocto.

### Edit

I found out that one can use `${AUTOREV}` in the `SRCREV` which upon every `bitbake -k recipe_name` should update the source code to updated commits. Should this be the preferred way?

Comment: I have similar problem, need to upgrade recipe under morty with a newer code revision outthere at external repo. Have you progress on yours?

Comment: after direct change SRCREV and PV but a new code is not fetched. Just used devtool build after recipes edited manually

Comment: I think the `${AUTOREV}` thing is the only way I could see it. Did `devtool build recipe_name` worked? @user3428154